# CSS grid auto-fill with always two columns

Tags: css, layout, css-grid, autofill

I have a grid container that has multiple labels and inputs. Is it possible to configure the grid in a way that it auto-fills the space with always two columns so that the label breaks the line with its corresponding input?

Grid before resize:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Label | Input | Label | Input | Label | Input |

Grid after resize:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Label | Input | Label | Input |
| Label | Input |  |  |

Comment: Plz share your code.

Comment: Basically, NO it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap inputs inside their label:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap:5px;
}


input{
  width:50%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <label>label <input type="text"></label>
  <label>label <input type="text"></label>
  <label>label <input type="text"></label>
  <label>label <input type="text"></label>
  <label>label <input type="text"></label>
  <label>label <input type="text"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide multiple tracks in the second argument of repeat and it will always fill to a multiple of that number of tracks.

In the case of auto-fill the tracks must be `<fixed-length>`. It is explained better by MDN [repeat() docs including auto-fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, max-content) minmax(50px, max-content));
  grid-gap:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <label>label</label> <input type="text">
  <label>label</label> <input type="text">
  <label>label</label> <input type="text">
  <label>label</label> <input type="text">
  <label>label</label> <input type="text">
  <label>label</label> <input type="text">
</div>
```